# GridView and Hidden Fields

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've got a Web app, in VB/ASPX, with a GridView fill with a SqlDataSource in my aspx file. Like this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" SkinID="dataGrid" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="id_session" HeaderText="id_session">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_id_session" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id_session") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_id_session" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id_session") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>




    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Formation_2014ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT s.id_session, f.libelle_formation, s.date_debut_session, s.date_fin_session, COUNT(p.id_personne) AS Expr1 FROM Sessions AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN Participe AS p ON p.id_session = s.id_session AND p.actif = 1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN Formation AS f ON f.id_formation = s.id_formation WHERE (s.date_fin_session > GETDATE()) OR (s.date_fin_session < GETDATE()) OR (S.date_fin_session = GETDATE()) GROUP BY s.id_session, f.libelle_formation, s.date_debut_session, s.date_fin_session" >
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This parts works, after that I'm hiding the first column, "id_session" with this code in my CodeBehind :

```
 Protected Sub OnRowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
        GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
        'e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False 'This way delete my paging
        (Requête)
    End Sub
```

And after that, I have to get the value of this Hidden column in my vb code, i'm trying different way but nothing ><

```
Dim id_session = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Controls(0).ToString 'Return System.Web.UI.Literalcontrol
Dim id_session = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex 'Return number of line
```

Sorry for my english, i'm French !

Comment: check the bellow solution, for any help just let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this method :

```
Dim id_session = (CType(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Controls(1), Label)).Text
```

It Work !

Answer (score 0):

use the Hiddenfield

try the following code insted of useing textbox in the firest column

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf_sessionId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("id_session") %>' />
```

it will not show to the UI and you can easily access the value from it
with this code you don't need the RowCreated event of the grid

dear remove this code

```
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_id_session" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id_session") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

and put the hiddenfield into the other itemtemplate which you want to display

Comment: When using HiddenField, and without RowCreated event, the column stay visible ! http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/19/1399361323-sans-titre2.png

Comment: dear you have to remove the txtbox and link controls form then grid kidly please show me your code after puting hidden field

Comment: `<asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="id_session" HeaderText="id_session">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_sessionId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("id_session") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_sessionId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("id_session") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>`

That's my code now, I found another way to proceed, but i'm wanted to see how to work with your solution !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False" change your code like this,

```
GridView1.Columns(0).style("display")="none"
```